# select columns from a line starting from specific word to last column in unix?

Tags: regex, perl, sed, awk, cut

Input file

```
1. blue is color
2. His shirt color is blue and it is good
3. deep blue see is a movie
```

output:

```
1. blue is color
2. blue and it is good
3. blue see is a movie
```

I need the output that start from specific word to last column in unix, using awk or cut.

Comment: `I need the output that start from ...` -- What did **you** try?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="\\<blue\\>"; OFS="blue"}{$1=""}7' file
```

the above line will output:

```
kent$  awk 'BEGIN{FS="\\<blue\\>"; OFS="blue"}{$1=""}7' file                                                                                                                   
blue is color
blue and it is good
blue see is a movie
```

Note that `"\\<blue\\>"` will match exactly word `blue`, not `bluesky or darkblue` I hope this is what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Code for [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
$ sed -r 's/^([0-9]+. ).* (blue)\b/\1\2/' file
1. blue is color
2. blue and it is good
3. blue see is a movie
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty common use case,

```
cat test.txt | awk '{ if (x=index($0,"blue")) { print substr($0,x,length($0)); } }'
```

I would recommend you to take a look at [Awk - A Tutorial and Introduction](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html#toc-uh-43)

Comment: and it is a pretty common useless cat call.

Comment: It's not going to make much difference, unless you're on a very loaded system

Comment: true, it's not going to make much difference for this example, however when learn/do things, and if there is clearly a better option, I would go that way. Well if you think single process is **not** better than multiple but useless processes, you could keep your opinion.

Comment: I agree with you up to the point. However, I'm always thinking about  real cases. I mean in a real case it would be a chain in a large pipeline of commands so from my point of view 'awk "{CODE}" file' is the degenerate case

Answer (score 0):

In Perl:

```
perl -nle'/(blue.*)/&&print"$1\n"'
```